# how to generate a link that opens Apple Plan or Google Maps

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, bubble.io

excuse my English.

I have to make a mobile app on bubble.io ( whitout code) I've found a little plugin for Html so I have to put a link that opens the good navigation app for each device. Apple Plans ( for ios) and Google Maps ( other device) or eventually Waze and other GPS App's

I have tried this one but i'm not sure if this is the right way:

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?q=lat,long" 
   href="https://goo.gl/maps/..." 
   target="_blank" rel="noopener"> link </a>
```

Is there a way to put a Javascript condition that displays the right link depending on the OS `enter code here`? I'm even not sure if this is possible on bubble.io.
Or some other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can open native map apps (iOS + Android):

- From the Design tab in bubble add a "Link" element to your page
- Set it to be an external link and in "Destination URL" put the url http://maps.apple.com/?q=50.501234,-0.123456

This would open Apple Maps app on iOS but on other devices you will be asked to choose Google Maps.